# How to convert a css only megamenu to jquery based

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, megamenu

I am using a megamenu in my site, which is purely css based. The disadvantage is that, it doesn't have any animation. The dropdown is getting show all on a sudden. So I am thinking of converting it to jquery based toggle. Here is the current code. How can I convert it to jQuery based?

```
.dropdown-1column, 
.dropdown-2columns, 
.dropdown-3columns, 
.dropdown-4columns,
.dropdown-5columns {
   margin:-1px auto  0 -285px;
   float:left;
   position:absolute;
   text-align:left;
   padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
   border:1px solid #dedede;
   background:#fff;
   z-index:999;
   display:none;    
}


.menu li:hover .dropdown-1column, 
.menu li:hover .dropdown-2columns, 
.menu li:hover .dropdown-3columns,
.menu li:hover .dropdown-4columns,
.menu li:hover .dropdown-5columns {
    display:block; 
}
```

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/gsTNS/

Comment: Animations exist in css3 if you don't have all to much restrictions on browser compatibility. What exactly do you want for an animation?

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Seeing the existing functionality would help

Comment: The dropdown should appear with an animation. Just like jquery slide down. I tried with opacity 0 and 1 trick. But it didn't worked because my dropdown uses a -285px towards the left.

Comment: @user632347 shouldn't matter

Comment: Just try applying the jQuery code to your current page and see what happens. Just try http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ to begin with.

Comment: @BillyMoat "Just apply jQuery and see what happens" not a good solution to any problem

Comment: @AJak : just added the fiddle

Comment: @BillyMoat : i tried most of the tricks i know :(

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gsTNS/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty much does what you're looking for I think. Could probably be refined:

http://jsfiddle.net/gsTNS/5/

Basically I've added a class of "has-dropdown" to each LI that has a dropdown and I've added a "dropdown" class to each dropdown DIV.

Then use jQuery to activate a slideToggle function:

```
jQuery("div#menu ul.menu li.has-dropdown").hover(
 function () {
   $(this).find("div.dropdown").slideToggle();
 },
 function () {
   $(this).find("div.dropdown").slideToggle();
 }
);
```

Comment: definitely need a stop() somewhere :)

Comment: @Billy Moat : Thanks it works like a magic.

Any soultion now to make it work for non javascript browsers too?

Comment: @Huangism : where to add that?

Comment: non javascript browser should use css only although I wouldn't worry about non javascript browsers